# How do I scale ticks and axes for high-resolution plots using CustomTicks?

Tags: plotting

I would like to scale this plot below to arbitrary size. For the font size it is straightforward, but

```
p[size_] := Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10},
            PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.002 (size/800)]},
            AxesStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[1.5 (size/800)], AbsoluteThickness[1 (size/800)]},
            TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 25 (size/800)],
            ImageSize -> size]
```

This code can be used to create plots with a custom width. Calling `p[800]` gives
[image]
whereas calling `p[2000]` gives
[image]
You can see perfectly well what is happening: the ticks disappear. I know that the package CustomTicks seemingly can solve this, but that is all I know. How do I specifiy the length (and thickness) of the ticks using this package?

Comment: Calling `p[2000]` certainly does not give the above result, but I see what you're getting at. You could use the `TickLengthScale` option in `CustomTicks`.

Comment: `CustomTicks` where?

Comment: @LLIAMnYP I think the forum software makes the images look more alike because they are both scaled to the same width. If you were to run my MWE from above, you would see that the above is the exact output. I will try to use the TickLengthScale option.

Comment: I recently started to prefer to use [`Magnify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Magnify.html).

Comment: @corey979 I tried Magnify, but it didn't scale the ticks for some reason. I was about to suggest it too.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the solution below scales fine:

```
<< CustomTicks`
p[size_] := Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10},
                PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.003]},
                AxesStyle -> {{Gray, AbsoluteThickness[2 (size/800)]},
                              {Gray, AbsoluteThickness[2 (size/800)]}},
                TicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 25 (size/800)],
                Frame -> False,
                Ticks -> {LinTicks[0, 10, 1, 2, MajorTickLength -> 0.01,
                                                MinorTickLength -> 0.005],
                          LinTicks[0, 100, 10, 2, MajorTickLength -> 0.01,
                                                  MinorTickLength -> 0.005]},
                ImageSize -> size]
p[800]
p[2000]
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I had in mind. +1 for the self-answer.